# Invisible table borders ReportLab

Tags: django, reportlab

I need to display some information on a ReportLab PDF that will be side by side. For example, below is a little pretend PDF. I have to have `Thing 1` and `Thing 2` beside each other with information below them.

`---------------------------
| Thing 1:       Thing 2:   |
| A-B-C          1-2-3      |
| D-E-F          4-5-6      |
|                           |
|                           |
-----------------------------`

I used Paragraph to start, but I couldn't find a way to make `Thing 1` and `Thing 2` line up. So I was thinking about using a table. Is there a way I can have multiple tables on a PDF that all have invisible borders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer, I just made the table borders and cells to the colour white.

`pdf_table.setStyle(TableStyle([('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.white), ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.white)]))`

---

Imports needed:

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.platypus.tables import TableStyle
```

Further reading about tables [here](https://docs.reportlab.com/reportlab/userguide/ch7_tables/).